# Merge two ASCII DEC values together and convert to int

Tags: arduino, type-conversion

i have two DEC variables and i would like to merge them like this:

```
unsigned int first_dig = 57;   // Number 9
unsigned int second_dig = 52;  // Number 4
unsigned int all_dig = 0;
```

Now i want to save them in all_dig. I already tried to shift bytes but it ends up in a Mess

```
all_dig = ((first_dig<<8)|second_dig); // prints 14644
```

I want all_dig to contain `94`. Is there a simpler way? I would like to use the same concept for three digits too.

Thanks already for the help

Comment: `all_dig = (first_dig - '0') * 10 + (second_dig - '0')`?

Comment: worked like a charm, thanks for the fast answer. For three digits i just need to write `first_dig *100 + sec_dig*10 + thrid_dig` , right

Comment: Just tried it with three digits (with substracting -'0'), didnt work. It prints 146 but it should print 194

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For two digits, `d_1, d_0`:

```
res = (d_1 - '0') * 10 + (d_0 - '0')
```

For three digits, `d_2, d_1, d_0`:

```
res = (d_2 - '0') * 100 + (d_1 - '0') * 10 + (d_0 - '0')
```

---

Notice that the expression is only valid if

```
'0' <= d_i <= '9' for each d_i
```

If that were not the case, the result wouldn't be correct.

Comment: i got it to work later but didnt look here anymore, thanks for the answer anyways